# Updating Jira tickets from Jenkins workflow (jenkinsfile)

Tags: jenkins, jira, jira-plugin, jenkins-cli, jenkins-workflow

How can I update a jira issue from within a [Jenkinsfile (jenkins-worflow/pipeline)](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md)? 
Is there a way I  could use the [Jira Issue Updater plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jira+Issue+Updater+Plugin) as a step in the Jenkinsfile?

I know I could use the Jira RestAPI, but I'm trying to figure out if I can re-use the functionality provided by the [jira-updater-issue](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jira+Issue+Updater+Plugin).

What I'm looking for is a something similar to the example below calling Junit archiver, and atifact archiver, but calling jira updater.

```
    node {
      git url: 'https://github.com/jglick/simple-maven-project-with-tests.git'
      def mvnHome = tool 'M3'
      sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn -B -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore verify"
      step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: '**/target/*.jar', fingerprint: true])
      step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'])
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

The [Jira Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Plugin) is compatible with Pipeline.

This should work:

```
step([$class: 'hudson.plugins.jira.JiraIssueUpdater', 
    issueSelector: [$class: 'hudson.plugins.jira.selector.DefaultIssueSelector'], 
    scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], 
        userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com/jglick/simple-maven-project-with-tests.git']]]])
```

You can get a full reference in the built-in Pipeline Snippet Generator.

Answer (score 2):

As this was way harder for me than it should be, here is a working example. This will update a custom field of a ticket with a specific value:

```
step([$class: 'IssueFieldUpdateStep',
        issueSelector: [$class: 'hudson.plugins.jira.selector.ExplicitIssueSelector', issueKeys: ticket],
        fieldId: field,
        fieldValue: value
    ])
```

The snippet generator did not work for me. The variables ticket, field and value are all strings. Starting from this you can look for options here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/jira/

Comment: Additionally, if you want to tag multiple tickets, the `ticket` String needs to be a comma-separated string of tickets, without ANY whitespace between the commas and the tickets.

Answer (score 0):

The [JIRA Steps Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Steps+Plugin) provides a more declarative way to [update an existing Jira Ticket](https://jenkinsci.github.io/jira-steps-plugin/jira_edit_issue.html):

```
node {
  stage('JIRA') {
    # Look at IssueInput class for more information.
    def testIssue = [fields: [ // id or key must present for project.
                               project: [id: '10000'],
                               summary: 'New JIRA Created from Jenkins.',
                               description: 'New JIRA Created from Jenkins.',
                               customfield_1000: 'customValue',
                               // id or name must present for issuetype.
                               issuetype: [id: '3']]]

    response = jiraEditIssue idOrKey: 'TEST-01', issue: testIssue

    echo response.successful.toString()
    echo response.data.toString()
  }
}
```

Since you would like to use the Jenkinsfile to define your pipeline, that should be the preferred way for you to go...

Answer (score 0):

Building on [amuniz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103811/amuniz)'s answer, if you're running in a pipeline that has already done a checkout, you can simplify this further:

```
step([$class: 'JiraIssueUpdater',
    issueSelector: [$class: 'hudson.plugins.jira.selector.DefaultIssueSelector'],
    scm: scm])
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, seems like this page answers your question:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jira+Issue+Updater+Plugin

After you install the plugin, add a build step, or pre/post build step to call this plugin

There you can give it the REST URL to your Jira server, the creds and the JQL to find the issues

Comment: Hi thanks, but I'm looking for an example using the jenkins-workflow dsl. I think the docs you're pointing to refer to using the jira-updater from a regular (non-workflow) project, right?

I mean, it tells you how to use the jenkins ui. What I'm looking for is the way to use it from a workflow jenkinsfile.

Comment: Agreed.  This is not an answer.