# Update Jira task from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jira, pipeline, jira-plugin

I need to update some jira tasks from Jenkins pipeline. I can add a label to JIRA tasks in this way:

```
step([$class       : 'hudson.plugins.jira.JiraIssueUpdater',
      issueSelector: [$class: 'hudson.plugins.jira.selector.DefaultIssueSelector'],
      scm          : scm,
      labels       : ["MYLABEL-2"]])
```

[image]

The problem is that I would like to update also other JIRA tasks by providing a jql query, something like:

```
step([$class       : 'hudson.plugins.jira.JiraIssueUpdater',
      issueSelector: [$class: 'hudson.plugins.jira.selector.JqlIssueSelector'],
      jql          : "project = TEST AND id = TEST-11",
      scm          : scm,
      labels       : ["MYLABEL"]])
```

The previous code is not working (there are no logs):

[image]

What Am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44631211/2047614

Comment: @MaratC I cannot use JIRA Steps Plugin, put only Jira Plugin or JIra REST API

Comment: Are you able to use the snippet generator for this?

Comment: @MattSchuchard unfortunatelly not. I can only use the jenkinsfile and open the web interface to check the result of the pipeline